# .NET core api will only model bind with root routes?

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, model-binding

I've found in my application that my posts will not model-bind (object is null) if I use the path combined by the class and method routes.  For example:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class MyController : ControllerBase
{
   [HttpPost("MyAction")]
   public async Task<IActionResult> MyAction(MyItem item)
```

In the above example, I can post to:  my-site/api/MyController/MyAction  but the item is null.  However if I instead change the route to

```
[HttpPost("/MyAction")]
```

I can post to my-site/MyAction and the same data will map to MyItem perfectly.

What is the difference in these two routing options that I'm missing here, and can I fix the first configuration to model bind correctly?

Comment: I make the demo to test  , but it worked well . It will be better if you could share the demo and the steps to reproduce the issue . You could also try create a new simple project to test .

Comment: How do you make the post request? I just tried this, I made a simple post request with json body with postman to your first sample action, and for me the model binder works fine. If you add the post request details to your question, that might help.